# How to MultiBinding too GeometryGroup

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, multibinding

I have a working MultiBinding with a `Path.Data` (Path here is `System.Windows.Shapes.Path`).
The Converter return type is `System.Windows.Media.PathGeometry`.

```
<Path.Data>
  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ToPathGeometryMultiConverter}">
    <Binding Path="A"/>
    <Binding Path="B"/>
    <Binding Path="C"/>
  </MultiBinding>-->
</Path.Data>
```

Now I want to change the structure a bit and add several geometries in a `GeometryGroup`. I don't know the syntax how to add `MultiBinding` here.

```
<Path.Data>                    
  <GeometryGroup>       
    <PathGeometry> 
     <!-- HOW CAN I MULTIBIND HERE --> 
    </PathGeometry>
  </GeometryGrounp>
<Path.Data>
```

Whatever I tried I always got a compile error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may bind the [`PathGeometry.Figures`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathgeometry.figures.aspx) property and have a converter that returns a [`PathFigureCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathfigurecollection.aspx), but I'm afraid you have to live with the fact that the VS Designer complains about the XAML.

```
<Path.Data>
    <GeometryGroup>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PathFiguresConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="A"/>
                    <Binding Path="B"/>
                    <Binding Path="C"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </PathGeometry.Figures>
        </PathGeometry>
    </GeometryGroup>
</Path.Data>
```

Comment: Thank you. That works. Do you know why the VS Designer complains, even if it compile and run fine?

Comment: As the message says, it expects that you add Figure items to the Figures collection, and of course a MultiBinding is not a Figure. Don't know why it cannot detect that its not adding items, but setting the property by a binding.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to put your binding code instead of PathGeometry tags

```
<Path.Data>                    
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ToPathGeometryMultiConverter}">
       <Binding Path="A"/>
       <Binding Path="B"/>
       <Binding Path="C"/>
    </MultiBinding>  
<Path.Data>
```

Comment: That don't work. It throws a XamlParseException. Multibinding cannot be used in a GeometryCollection. Additional Info: it needs a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

Comment: Remove GeometryGroup tags too

Comment: Are you kidding me? Did you read my Question? The 'solution' you gave me is the working code i had at the start. Now i want to extend the program and add GeometryGroup (a collection of several different Geometries).